# set value for random element on matrix

Tags: java, for-loop, matrix

I'm trying to generate a 8 by 8 matrix. Each element of matrix needs to have a value of 1 except one element on each column which is set as 0, that one element is chosen by generating a random int between 0-7.

What I get when I run the code:

```
   1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1  
   1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1  
   1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1  
   1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1  
   1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1  
   1     0     0     1     1     1     1     1  
   1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1  
   1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1
```

My matrix should look like this:

```
   1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1  
   1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1  
   1     1     1     1     1     0     1     0  
   0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1  
   1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1  
   1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1  
   1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1  
   1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1
```

code

```
    for (int[] row: grid)
        Arrays.fill(row, 1);

    for (int i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {
       int j = getRandom();
       grid[i][j] = 0;
    }

    // print matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            System.out.format("%2s%2d%2s", " ", Main.grid[i][j], " ");

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @Alex if you run the code, you'll see that it skips some of the columns or creates two 0 values in the same column.

Comment: Aah ok. It's 'cause you put both those tasks inside the innermost loop, causing them both to run once per cell. You need to set the cell to 1 on every cell, but you only need to pick a 0 once per column

Comment: Note your second example has duplicates in the rows / rows of all 1s

Comment: @Rogue OP is showing the actual results and comparing it to the expected results

Comment: I get that, but I think the assumption was to uniquely disperse them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your nested loop, both initialization and nulling of cells are in the innermost loop. This will cause both to run once per cell, but nulling is only done once per column.

If we change the order that the cells are initialized in from row after row to column after column, we can move the nulling logic out to the outermost loop.

```
for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
    for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++) {
        Main.grid[r][c] = 1;
    }

    Main.grid[getRandom()][c] = 0; // assuming your getRandom() is within range
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly let's make the matrix all 1s:

```
//fill however you like
int[][] matrix = IntStream.range(0, 8).mapToObj(i
                 -> IntStream.range(0, 8).map(i -> 1).toArray());
```

Then, based on your question, it seems like you want a unique row per column to have a zero. So just shuffle your column indexes:

```
List<Integer> rows = IntStream.range(0, 8).collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(rows); //random rows per 0-8 column
AtomicInteger column = new AtomicInteger();
//iterate columns, and select random row
rows.forEach(i -> matrix[i][column.getAndIncrement()] = 0);
```

This'll disperse the random 0s to be unique per row (and column), and there's not really any RNG involved so it's O(n)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use the Arrays.fill api, it will make your code much cleaner and concise.

```
int[][] matrix = new int[m][n];
// Fill each row with 1
for (int[] row: matrix)
    Arrays.fill(row, 1);
```

Then, for each row, pick a column number at random and insert '0' thereby replacing the 1.

```
for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
   int j = Math.Random(0,matrix[0].length); // Or any other api for random number generation
   matrix[i][j] = 0;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I still have the same problem. Some columns are skipped without a 0, some have multiple 0's. I updated the code.